# How To Paginate A Long Text Post

Tags: java, jquery, grails, list, pagination

I'm Creating  a website for online reading stories using grails and i'm facing a business problem that if i post a story say 30 pages A4 in the Fckeditor and it had saved will .. the question is how can i display this in a 30 pages with a pagination or something like that.. do anyone have idea cause i'm out of simple ideas and i think making many lists of the story is a rough idea.. so is there any java/grails/groovy or even jQuery idea that can save my day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to have to write some custom code here.

If you want to auto-paginate, then you'll have to index into the string and grab a fixed number of characters, words, paragraphs, or whatever makes sense. If you don't need to auto-paginate, then you can embed pagination information in the text string. Either way you'll have to expose a page number field in the view, then use that to page into the text based on what the user provided.

Sorry I don't have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to do it client-side then there are jQuery options, such as [SimplePager plugin](http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/20/simplepager---jquery-paging-plugin--updated) or [jQuery Paginate](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination). You will probably need your HTML to be divided into "segments" such as DIVs or LIs or something divisible, though.

Comment: actually i need it to be server side :D